# Is it customary to use a transistor at the end of a string of logic gates when powering something such as a relay?

Tags: transistors, current, digital-logic

I have a pretty simple circuit - a clock (555 timer), counter, some logic gates, and a relay. Essentially, the clock's state, combined with some logic, will determine if the relay is on or off.

My question is if I need a transistor (or if it's just best practice when driving something in general, and why) to run the relay. The 555's max output current is 225mA, and the relay's coil current is 71-90mA, so *in theory* I think it's fine. I'm still an EE student, so I'd like to learn to do this "correctly."

Edit: Here's a basic logic schematic from Logisim (also if anyone has suggestions for more advanced digital logic simulation software, go for it).
Basically when the relay LED is illuminated, I want the relay to be on. My question pertains to whether or not I can hook the output of that OR gate directly to the relay, or do I need to insert a transistor between the two?
[image: Logic Schematic]

Comment: Your question's title is not consistent with the text. The title talks about an transistor and logic gates, but in the text you are talking about the drive of a 555. I think we need to see a schematic of how the relay will be connected to everything else.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson updated!

Comment: If the OR gate is to power the relay, then you need to look into what current the OR gate can source/sink. For example, the [74x32 series](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls32.pdf?ts=1620393468961&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fen.wikipedia.org%252F).

Comment: @rdtsc ah, that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good learning opportunity.

The ability of a logic gate to sink current will be listed as its \$I_{OL}\$ in the data sheet. So, pick the specific OR gate that you want to use and check its data sheet. Keep in mind that the specified current value will not be for an output of 0.00 V, but probably for the particular gates specified output voltage for a low logic level \$V_{OL}\$.

If the current required by your relay exceeds the current available from the logic gate then you must add something to drive the higher current. That added "something" can be a transistor, either a BJT or MOSFET, but the details will depend on the operating voltage of your logic and relay. You have not given us either of those specifications.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, it'll all be at 5V. I'm probably going to use a TI CD4071BE for that OR gate. [The Data Sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/CD4071B) has a table on page 1, with I_OL and I_OH - although there's a lot of different cells. Would I look under the "VO" conditions?

Comment: You only need to look at the row for Vdd = 5V. The Vo column tells you the output voltage, and the columns to the right tell you how much current you can expect for different operating temperature ranges. As you can see, it is much much less than your relay will require.

Comment: Got it, yes it definitely is way too low! Good thing they hammered BJTs into our brains for 2 years straight haha. Thanks again!